# EJB3.0 Updating a field in a table with the same value

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0

I have a database table 'MyTable' that has a trigger upon update of field 'Status' in it.

Below is a dummy-code of what i'm trying to do:

```
MyTable table = new Mytable();
table.setTableId(1);
table.setStatus ("NEW");
em.persist (table); //At this point the trigger did not kick in since this inserted a new record

...

MyTable table2 = em.find(MyTable.class, 1);
table2.setStatus ("NEW"); 
em.merge(table2)//Even though im updating the record with the same status with the same value, i still want the trigger to kick. However the trigger is not being activated.


...

MyTable table3 = em.find(MyTable.class, 1);
table3.setStatus ("OLD"); 
em.merge(table3)//The trigger is being activated here since the status is different the status value when it was inserted the first time.
```

Long story short, how can i make the changes done to 'transfer2' to trigger an update even though the status is the same?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA does not update object that have no changes.

You could try changing to something else (flush), then changing it back.

You could also use a JPQL update query to update it.

Depending on your JPA provider you could probably force it to update fields that have not changed, but this would lead to very bad performance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `em.flush();` to synchronize the persistence context to the underlying database. Your pending queries shall be send to database, but you still can have a complete rollback.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try updating the enity and commit the transaction, without using merge.

Like

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
MyTable table2 = em.find(MyTable.class, 1); 
table2.setStatus ("NEW");  

//em.merge(table2)//Even though im updating the record with the same status with the
// same value, i still want the trigger to kick. However the trigger is not being activated.  
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Hello, the thing is is that there are other operations within the same transaction. Therefore, i want the ability to rollback all my DB operations in case an error takes place, so committing the transaction is not an option.